# rqt window empty

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, rqt, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the command `rqt` on my computer to display topics in the topic list but the window which pops up is empty, I can see just the title from the taskbar "Default -rqt".

Tutorial: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/topic_monitor/#topic-monitor

ROS version: Kinetic

Turtlebot3 Waffle Pi

Ubuntu Xenial

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329339/rqt-window-empty/) by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the top of window, see plugin -> Topics -> Topic Monitor.

---

Originally posted by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) with karma: 91 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on 2019-07-26**:
I do not have anything on top of the window, I have tried to find it.